# Plotting Shortest Path to graph

Tags: python

I have a set of coordinates and would like to find the shortest path from the coordinates closest to x=0,y=0 to the coordinate that is furthest away from it and display it on the graph. Is there anyway I could do that?

Here are coordinates of interest:

```
23 292
78 275
187 81
188 430
198 150
204 180
222 245
223 175
226 334
255 344
263 213
266 261
286 163
301 266
328 206
352 42
363 169
379 177
385 187
394 211
400 254
401 199
412 335
420 371
434 176
449 174
457 230
472 136
```

In addition to this, would it be possible to find the diameter of the graph (from a to b)too?

Comment: You can use `((x2-x1)**2 + (y2-y1)**2)**0.5` to find the distance between two points (if you only need to figure out the closest/furthest, skip the square root as it is quite slow).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should get you started. I haven't made it pretty in any way, but the basics are there
for you to build on.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

xy = np.array([[23, 292], [78, 275], [187, 81], [188, 430], [198, 150], [204, 180],         
              [222, 245], [223, 175], [226, 334], [255, 344], [263, 213], [266, 261], 
              [286, 163], [301, 266], [328, 206], [352, 42], [363, 169], [379, 177], 
              [385, 187], [394, 211], [400, 254], [401, 199], [412, 335], [420, 371],
              [434, 176], [449, 174], [457, 230], [472, 136]])
lengths = np.linalg.norm(xy, axis=1)
minindex = np.argmin(lengths)
maxindex = np.argmax(lengths)
diameter = lengths[maxindex] - lengths[minindex]
linex = (xy[minindex, 0], xy[maxindex, 0])
liney = (xy[minindex, 1], xy[maxindex, 1])
plt.scatter(xy[:, 0], xy[:, 1])
plt.plot(linex, liney)
plt.show()
```

Not totally sure about your `diameter` question but I had an idea.